# Why is the trait `core::fmt::Show` not implemented for the type `core::fmt::Show + Sized`?

Tags: rust

I am trying to compile some code, but I'm getting a pretty weird error:

> the trait `core::fmt::Show` is not implemented for the type `core::fmt::Show + Sized`

And the code:

```
use std::fmt::Show;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", return_showed()); // Error occurs here
}

fn return_showed() -> Box<Show+Sized+'static> {
    box "test" as Box<Show+Sized>
}
```

This doesn't make much sense to me. Is this a bug in the compiler?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add a bit more why you need `+Sized`?

Comment: @Shepmaster In my actual code I need a Sized. This is just a simplified test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rust 1.0**

The code posted in the original question compiles as expected now.

**Original**

If you don't need `Sized`, then you can use this:

```
fn show_boxed() -> Box<Show+'static> { // '
    box "test"
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", &*show_boxed());
}
```

As I understand it, `&*` will dereference and then re-reference the Box. This changes it from a `Box<core::fmt::Show>` to a `&core::fmt::Show`, which the formatting machinery knows how to deal with.

**Edit**

You can also pick out just the trait object you want:

```
fn return_showed() -> Box<Show+Sized+'static> { // '
    box "test" as Box<Show+Sized>
}

fn main() {
    let z: &Show = &*return_showed();
    println!("{}", z);
}
```

I agree that this is less-than-ideal; it may be worth filing a Rust issue.

Comment: I'd still like to know what causes this error though.